# How to read Title name Using Pywinauto

Tags: python, pywinauto

How to read the Title name below is the code

```
from pywinauto.application import *
import time
app=Application.Start("apps.exe")
app.window_(title="aps a.b.c.d")
time.sleep(2)
```

After that code is giving error like `window is not found`.

So, my question is how to pass `aps a.b.c.d` to the window title.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to accomplish here, as the code you have provided doesn't throw any errors (I tried it with Notepad.exe and it works).  What exactly are you trying to do here, and what isn't working?  Can you provide code that shows the error?

Comment: I have screen called aps a.b.c.d when I am running with the above code giving error "No window found"

Comment: @user157530 Then there must be something else going on here, but you haven't provided much data to work with.  What is the exact text of the error?  What version of Python are you using?  What version of pywinauto are you using?  What version of Windows are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed pywinauto can cause really subtile timing errors.  If this is your issue, this isn't even a bad one.

Just because the process has been started does not mean the window exists and is fully formed.  your sleep should be after Application.Start().  But this is a sloppy solution that won't work on all systems in all situations.

I have resorted to using len( pwa_app.windows_() ) and pwa_app.top_window_() to ensure the Application is in a state I want.

This however has it's down sides. those to functions seem to have the ability to cause exceptions when a window is being created or destroyed.  So instead of using a plain time.sleep() call, I usually have something like this.

```
#Do While Loop; continuous retry on exception
condition = True
while condition:
    try:
        window_count = len( app.windows_() )
    except:
        continue

    if window_count == num:
        condition = False
    else:
        time.sleep( WAITTIME )
```

I would love if someone could explain a better method to me.  I have not been able to find any mention of these issues in the documentation.  While this is not elegant, and pounds the CPU, it works 100% of the time.

**EDIT**

While browsing Stack Overflow, I found out pywinauto provides a [function](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code/pywinauto.timings.html) that does *exactly* what my example does.